# Redirect POST data to server with least load

Tags: php, post, amazon-ec2

I want to use jQueryFileUpload (http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload data, especially music to a server where it gets processed. I want to have a script on a normal webserver that redirects the currently uploading file to the server which has the least load. 
These Servers are Amazon EC2 instances, monitored by Amazon CloudWatch. If the average usage of all EC2 Instance is higher than 70%, new instances are fired up.

Is that possible?
How can I get the Serverload into the PHP-redirection script?
How to handle the $_POST data to redirect?

Comment: Does jQueryFileUpload support sending `Expect: 100-continue` headers? This will be a pre-requisite, I would say. As an extension of this, I don't think you will be able to do it (effectively) with PHP, since you would want the `Expect:` behaviour, and PHP is not fired up until the entire request - including the body - has been received. I personally would do this with a little Node.js program, but that is a point of personal preference.

Comment: The basic architecture would be `Client POST with Expect:` => `Server checks loads and sends 307 redirect for appropriate server` => `Client POST to correct server`

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yeah, you're architecture is exactly what i want. But has anyone an idea to get the ec2 serverload into the php script? Possible with another php script and `shell_exec("uptime");` ?

Comment: Surely CloadWatch provides some kind of API that you can poll for the server loads? I don't know, I have never used any of the Amazon hosting services before, but it seems to me that it would be one of the more basic bits of functionality...?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2534

Comment: Apparently the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) supports the CloudWatch - you should be able to aquire the information you need into PHP with that. Although as I say, I doubt you would be able to get the 100-continue -based method to work with PHP because of the way it works